# Как привязать контекст к функции, вызываемой в обработчике?

Tags: javascript

На диве обработчик, в котором вызывается функция. В previewDocument нужно оперировать с this, который должен указывать на этот див. Но он указывает на window.

```
<div onclick=previewDocument("argument")>
```

Answer (score 1):

надо в функцию передать тот самый `this`

```
<div onclick=previewDocument(this, "argument")>
```

а в  функции ловить в виде первого аргумента